# Why do I have more observations in my Multiple Linear Regression than I do rows in my dataframe in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, mlr

I'm running an MLR in R examining the effects of 4 explanatory variables (Temperature, Dissolved Oxygen, Practical Salinity, and Oxidative Reductive Potential) on 1 response variable (Shell Roundness):

```
shell_round_mlr <- lm(Shell_Round ~ TempC + O2 + PSU + ORP, data = morph.na)
```

The dataset (morph.na) in question has **53 rows** of data. When I run the following code to examine the model...

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(shell_round_mlr)
```

I get these plots:

[Residuals vs. Fitted Value, Normal Q-Q, Scale-Location, Residuals vs. Leverage]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkkmd.png

Which show observations #65 and #159 as ones I would possibly like to remove. However, **how is it possible that I have an observation #159, when I only have 53 rows of data?** I have triple-checked that I am calling the correct dataframe.

Also, in this case, if I would want to remove any of these troublesome observations, how would I go about doing that? It is not as simple as removing a row from the dataframe.

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Does your dataset have row names in it? It may be those number are based on the row names, not your total # observations. Try setting the `labels.id` argument to `NULL`  in your `plot()` call to use observation numbers. (You can see this argument in the help page for `plot.lm`, `?plot.lm`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to diagnose your problem without a reproducible example.  But as @aosmith noted in a comment, `plot` will use row indices for labeling.  This example shows `lm` plots with labelled values above the total sample size.

```
set.seed(1L)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20))
rownames(df) <- sample(50:70, 20)

fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)

plot(fit)
```

[image]

By comparison, here's the same plot with `labels.id = NULL`:

```r
plot(fit, labels.id = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: What do you think about adding an example showing how to use `labels.id = NULL` to get the observation number instead?